# Solving inequalities with squared terms

Tags: inequality

Solve $$1-x^2 \geq 0$$
I subtracted the $1$, and the inequality became $-x^2 \geq -1$, therefore $x^2 \leq 1$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1 - x^2 \geq 0 \iff (1 - x)(1 + x) \geq 0$. Can you take it from here...?.

Alternately, if you want the $x$ to be on one side, then from $x^2 \leq 1$, taking square-root both sides:

$|x| = \sqrt{x^2} \leq \sqrt{1} = 1$. So:

$|x| \leq 1 \Rightarrow -1 \leq x \leq 1$

Comment: the x has to be on one side, can you show me working out please

Comment: @Ishamel: see edit.

Comment: $x^2 \leq 1$ implies $|x| \leq 1$ then $-1 \leq x \leq 1$

Comment: @LAcarguy. You won by less than $1$ second ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Cool!